# Why Xna doesn't load .fx files

Tags: c#, graphics, visual-studio-2013, textures, xna-4.0

I'm learning Xna, and I have some trouble with loading non .xnb file formats.
I don't know why, but Xna searches only for .xnb files.
Here is my code:

```
Effect simpleColorEffect;
simpleColorEffect = Content.Load<Effect>("SimpleColor");
```

I saw some solutions for this, but they didn't work.
How can i solve this?

I would thank you any advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put specific file into Content folder and make sure that content processor for that file is set to Effect - XNA framework.